# how use Minitest:Spec on Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest, specifications

I'm want use Minitest:Spec on Rails 4 but the minitest methods like subject and before dosen't work

this is my gemfile

```
group :test do
    # gem "mocha", :require => false
    gem "mocha", :require => false
    gem 'minitest-reporters'
    gem 'minitest-rails'
    gem 'minitest-spec-rails'
    gem 'shoulda-matchers', require: false
    gem "minitest-matchers_vaccine"
    gem 'simplecov'
end
```

and this is my helper

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
require "minitest/rails"
require 'shoulda/matchers'
require "minitest/reporters"
require 'mocha/mini_test'
```

and my application

```
config.generators do |g|
   g.test_framework :minitest, spec: true
end
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I just tried this on a clean Rails 4.2.0 app and both `before` and `subject` works fine, so something else must be going on.

Comment: Which version of Rails? 4.2? 4.1? or 4.0?

Comment: I have also been successful with your dependencies on a fresh Rails 4.2 app. Please provide more info like error messages so we can help you.